# Div alignment issues on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, alignment

I have this site here http://thornwoodfinehomes.com and on the home page I have a centered gallery and this is the case in all browser except IE7. In IE7 the gallery is aligning to the right.

How do I center this in ie 7?

the div structure for the gallery goes `.tn3gallery1`, `.tn3e-gallery`, `.tn3e-image1` ... below is the CSS:

```
.tn3gallery1 {
margin-left: -42px;
margin-top: -30px;
}

.tn3e-gallery {
position: relative;
width: 1067px;
height: auto;
line-height: normal;
}

.tn3e-image {
border: 3px solid #93928D;
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 20px;
width: 1067px;
height: 450px;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I think it might be some problems with the slideshow gallery. The image width has been exceed the size of the wrapper/main. Maybe you should check on it first.

Comment: You haven't used margin: 0 auto; anywhere which is the standard method of centering divs, and .tn3gallery1 as the wrapper doesn't have a width set. I can't see why you've used negative margins. IE doesn't cope well with negative margins.